# Selecting XmlNode's Child Nodes based on Tag

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse this XML Document:

```
<MPD>
  <Period duration="PT0H3M1.63S" start="PT0S">
    <AdaptationSet>
      <ContentComponent contentType="video" id="1" />
      <Representation bandwidth="4190760" codecs="avc1.640028" height="1080" id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" width="1920">
        <BaseURL>car-20120827-89.mp4</BaseURL>
      </Representation>
      <Representation bandwidth="2073921" codecs="avc1.4d401f" height="720" id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" width="1280">
        <BaseURL>car-20120827-88.mp4</BaseURL>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet>
      <ContentComponent contentType="audio" id="2" />
      <Representation bandwidth="127236" codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="6" mimeType="audio/mp4" numChannels="2" sampleRate="44100">
        <BaseURL>car-20120827-8c.mp4</BaseURL>
      </Representation>
      <Representation bandwidth="255236" codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="7" mimeType="audio/mp4" numChannels="2" sampleRate="44100">
        <BaseURL>car-20120827-8d.mp4</BaseURL>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

using this C# code:

```
var rootDoc = new XmlDocument();
rootDoc.LoadXml(xmlString); // the one from above

var adaptationSets = rootDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AdaptationSet");

if (adaptationSets.Count > 0)
    foreach (XmlNode adaptionSet in adaptationSets) // Loop through AdaptionSets
    {
        // Get the one Node in this AdaptionSet with the ContentComponent-Tag
        var contentComponent = adaptionSet.SelectSingleNode("ContentComponent");

        if (contentComponent != null)
        {
            // parse attributes
        }

        // Get All Nodes in this AdaptionSet with the Representation-Tag
        var representations = adaptionSet.SelectNodes("Representation");

        if(representations?.Count > 0)
            foreach (XmlNode representation in representations)
            {
                // parse attributes of XmlNode
            }
    }
```

It all works except for the XPath queries. I tried a lot of variations with leading "/", "//", "./" and without any leading characters, but it just won't work. What am I doing wrong? I'm not using XPath on a regular basis and I couldn't find anything more than the leading characters I mentioned. Because I've seen it on a lot of other answers on this website I feel like I should mention that I'm explicitly looking for the XPath that will help me solve this, not some Linq variation or an entirely different approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem:

```
var rootDoc = new XmlDocument();
rootDoc.LoadXml(xmlString); // the one from above

var adaptationSets = rootDoc.SelectNodes("//AdaptationSet");

if (adaptationSets.Count > 0)
    foreach (XmlNode adaptionSet in adaptationSets) // Loop through AdaptionSets
    {
        // Get the one Node in this AdaptionSet with the ContentComponent-Tag
        var contentComponent = adaptionSet.SelectSingleNode("./ContentComponent");

        if (contentComponent != null)
        {
            // parse attributes
        }

        // Get All Nodes in this AdaptionSet with the Representation-Tag
        var representations = adaptionSet.SelectNodes("./Representation");

        if (representations?.Count > 0)
            foreach (XmlNode representation in representations)
            {
                // parse attributes of XmlNode
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement period = doc.Descendants("Period").FirstOrDefault();

            MPD mpd = new MPD();
            mpd.duration = (string)period.Attribute("duration");
            mpd.start = (string)period.Attribute("start");
            mpd.adaptions = period.Elements("AdaptationSet").Select(x => new Adaption() {
                contentType = (string)x.Element("ContentComponent").Attribute("contentType"),
                id = (int)x.Element("ContentComponent").Attribute("id"),
                representations = x.Elements("Representation").Select(y => new Representation() {
                    bandwidth = (int)y.Attribute("bandwidth"),
                    codecs = (string)y.Attribute("codecs"),
                    height = (int?)y.Attribute("height"),
                    id = (int)y.Attribute("id"),
                    mimeType = (string)y.Attribute("mimeType"),
                    width = (int?)y.Attribute("width"),
                    baseURL = (string)y.Descendants("BaseURL").FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class MPD
    {
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public List<Adaption> adaptions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Adaption
    {
        public string contentType { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Representation> representations { get; set; }
    }
    public class Representation
    {
        public int bandwidth { get; set; }
        public string codecs { get; set; }
        public int? height { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string mimeType { get; set; }
        public int? width { get; set; }
        public string baseURL { get; set; }
    }

}
```